# a few wierd problems with the ardrone_autonomy

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys, I have installed the ardrone dirver on my laptop and I am having a few problems when when using it with Ardrone 2.0.

1. After running the driver, I used this command  **rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata**, what I find is that the **altd** and **vz** are always 0 while vz, vy are updating.
2. It is found that the **video_channel**  parameter either being 1 or 0, the image is always published to the **/ardrone/front/image_raw** and **/ardrone/image_raw**. The **/ardrone/bottom/image_raw** topic always has nothing.
3. I have a node subscribing to the **/ardrone/image_raw (callback1)** and **/ardrone/imu (callback2)** topic. I set up a counter that is incremented by 1 in the callback2 function. In the callback1 function, I first print the counter and then set it to 0. What I notice is that the counter value varies a lot. I mean the IMU data is published at 200Hz and the image at 20 Hz. the counter should be around 10, right ?

I really appreciate it if anyone can help with these issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190796/a-few-wierd-problems-with-the-ardrone_autonomy/) by [z3391384](https://answers.ros.org/users/20056/z3391384/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that it's been a while, but from what I know about the AR.Drone and ardrone_autonomy here's my input:

1. Is AR.Drone flying? If it's not, then you should see **altd** showing 0. The velocities are estimated using the bottom camera and they're only going to estimate the **x** and **y** velocities, not **z**.
2. The video is streamed from the front camera automatically along the **/ardrone/front/...** topics. Unfortunately, the AR.Drone 2.0 doesn't support streaming both cameras at the same time.In order to get a video stream form the bottom camera along the **/ardrone/bottom/...** topics you need to call a service to switch cameras using `rosservice call /ardrone/togglecam` or something similar. Using tab to automatically fill in your commands is very useful.
3. Not really sure what you're getting at here.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1